# Using sed with regex, how do I add characters at the end of a line with a variable length recurring match from the start

Tags: regex, sed

I have a Markdown file with the single or increasingly repeated '#' characters, at the start of a line, that marks headings in descending order, i.e. one hash is heading 1 and two hashes is heading 2 etc.

I would like to convert the heading style to the style that uses the '=' character at both the start and end of the line.

(This is across multiple files, hence my desire to use sed.)

Example:

```
# Heading 1

Some text

## Heading 2

Some more text

### Heading 3

And more
```

Converts to:

```
= Heading 1 =

Some text

== Heading 2 ==

Some more text

=== Heading 3 ===

And more
```

I only want to use sed for this (don't judge me) and I have no problem making the initial match. My challenge is how to add the same number of '=' characters at the end of lines where I match and replace the '#' character(s)?

Footnote: I searched Stackoverflow and other sites and found nothing that covers appending a variable number of characters based on the number of characters in a match. I also asked Chat-GPT but, as I have often found, that just ended in a circular dialog, where I got my own question re-worked and presented as an answer. I therefore plucked up the courage to post here, even though I have been beaten up in the past for not asking the perfect question. Please be kind ;)

Comment: LoL. I got voted down within seconds. You've got to love this site, NOT!

Comment: The same dude removed one of my tags! No conversation just right up went and removed it. His down vote edit seems to have vanished now.

Comment: Why is Stackoverflow such a bullying environment?

Comment: Can you share your attempt at solving this problem?

Comment: It is not SO as a whole @DavidSavage, just a few select individuals, one of which you seem to have encountered. It would help if you could provide what you have tried rather than where has been searched even if the command failed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With GNU `sed` you could try:

```
sed -E 's/^#(.*)/=\1 =/;:a;s/^(=*)#(.*)/\1=\2=/;ta'
```

We first replace any `#SOMETHING` line with `=SOMETHING =` (`s/^#(.*)/=\1 =/`). We need this special treatment to add a space before the trailing `=`. Next, we add a loop label (`:a`). Then, we replace `=...=#SOMETHING` with `=...==SOMETHING=` (`s/^(=*)#(.*)/\1=\2=/`) and we loop (`ta`) as long as there are `#`.

Note that technically, if you have lines with a leading mixture of `#` and `=`, we should be a bit more specific and don't touch them. Example:

```
sed -E '/^#+\s.*\S/{s/(#+)(.*\S)\s*/\1\2 /;:a;s/^(=*)#(.*)/\1=\2=/;ta}'
```

Comment: Awesome, both in the fact this works and in that it was a friendly interaction. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

Using `awk`:

```bash
awk '{
  where=match($0,"^#+"); 
  if (where) {
    out=""; 
    prefix="";
    for(i=1;i<=RLENGTH;i++){
      prefix=prefix"="
    }; 
    suffix=prefix; 
    for (i=2;i<=NF;i++){
      out=out$i
    }; 
    print prefix " " out " " suffix 
  } 
  else {print $0}}
'
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion and the polite interaction. I will however, park this until I take on awk as my next learning challenge. For now I'll go with the sed answer from Renaud Pacalet.

Comment: @DavidSavage No worries. If I had to guess why your question was downvoted, I'd probably say it is because it did not show your attempt at solving the problem. So going forward, make sure you do include that in the question. See also https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @Paolo With `awk` you could also try something a bit simpler, like `'/^#+[[:space:]]/ {gsub(/#/,"=",$1);$(NF+1)=$1} 1'`

Answer (score 0):

This would be much less convoluted and arcane using awk, e.g. with GNU awk for the 3rd arg to `match()`:

```
$ awk '
    match($0,/^(#+)(.*)/,a) {
        gsub(/#/,"=",a[1])
        $0 = a[1] a[2] " " a[1]
    }
    { print }
' file
= Heading 1 =

Some text

== Heading 2 ==

Some more text

=== Heading 3 ===

And more
```

or portably using any awk in any shell on every Unix box:

```
awk '
    match($0,/^#+/) {
        hd = substr($0,1,RLENGTH)
        tl = substr($0,RSTART+RLENGTH)
        gsub(/#/,"=",hd)
        $0 = hd tl " " hd
    }
    { print }
' file
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion and the polite interaction. However, my question was focused on using sed with regex.

Comment: @DavidSavage understood but this site exists to create a catalogue where someone with a problem can look up that problem and find answers to it, not just to help the person who originally asked the question, so adding answers that provide reasonable alternatives using similarly-available tools is acceptable and normal practice here.